# How to share the current page with the Facebook, Twitter, Whatsapp and Messenger share button?

Tags: html

I have added the Facebook, WhatsApp, Twitter and Messenger share buttons to my webpage. However all the buttons share a specific link, what I would like is for the buttons to share the page that they are currently on, I have tried some suggestions which I have found on stack overflow but they have either not worked or not been suitable for what I am trying to achieve. Any suggestions would be great thank you!

My code:

```
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous"src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v4.0"></script>
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <a data-href="https://example.com" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
    </a>

    <a href=”fb-messenger://share/?link= https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&app_id=000000000”>
    </a>


    <a data-href="https://example.com" href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">
    </a>


    <a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=example.com" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use onclick tag and getting current link with location.href method.

```html
<a onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + location.href)">here is your link</a>
```